# Azure Kubernetes Persistant Volume Azure Disk

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I am using Azure Kubernetes and I have created Persistent Volume, Claims and Storage Class.

I want to deploy pods on the Persistent Volume so we can increase the Volume anytime as per the requirement. Right now our Pods are deployed in the Virtual Machines OS Disk. Since we are using the default Pods deployment on the VM Disk when we run out of the disk space the whole cluster will be destroyed and created again.

Please let me know how can I configure Pods to deploy in Azure (Managed) Disk.

Thanks,
Mrugesh

Comment: I have created PersistentVolumeClaim and It created the Storage.
Now I am deploying the application to Kubernetes. below is the yaml file for deployment.
But still the Pods are using the OS Disk for deployment. Please suggest.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wG9vyZ5h1BRgUr6e4haxYWJ1ix3f9r0Y5VOfUyYgzjs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you should edit the question and add that yaml.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a Persistent Volume manually, if you want Azure Disk, this can be created dynamically for you.

From [Azure Built-in storage classes](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv.md#built-in-storage-classes):

> The default storage class provisions a standard SSD Azure disk.
> Standard storage is backed by Standard SSDs and delivers cost-effective storage while still delivering reliable performance.

You only have to create the `PersistentVolumeClaim` with the storage class you want to use, e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azure-managed-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: default
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

and then refer to that PVC in your Deployment or Pods.